# Django deleting entries from database

Tags: django, sqlite

When i delete an entry from the Person table in SQLlite database, is there a way so that the ID changes to the number of entries in the table?
For example,
I deleted Id=5 but then there is a gap from Id=4 to Id=6

```
class Person(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5C6I5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sql databases use the id as a primary key. This key by default is set to auto increment. This makes sure that every row in the database has a unique identity as in even all feilds in two rows are same they are still different. Hence you cannot change all row id's every time you delete a row. You can find more information about this on Google, a good place to start is 'why databases have primary key'.